# Updgrade from resty-gwt 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: java, gwt, resty-gwt

I have recently upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4

However there have been a number of snags.
Most I have been able to resolve, however this one I have no idea where to even start.

This is a crude ezample of the POJO

```
public class Pizza {
  public String    name;
  public PizzaBase base;
  public Object    testObject;
}
```

I am passing a newly instantiated object to the REST service and would expect this as my post body :

```
{
 "name" : null,
 "base" : null,
 "testObject" : null
}
```

however I am getting this:

```
{
 "name" : null,
 "testObject" : null
}
```

I have looked everywhere to see if there are any annotations i have missed, but to no avail.

I have not configured any custom encoders myself, letting resty do all the work.
I have set Defaults.dontIgnoreJsonNulls()

I then updgraded to the latest version of resty, and this problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the 1.3 `Defaults.setIgnoreJsonNullsOnObjects(false);` that was removed